# In which year was the triple equals sign introduced to javascript?

Tags: javascript

In which year was the triple equals sign introduced to JavaScript?

Bonus points for

`==`

`===`

`Object.is`

and any equality checks that I am missing.

Comment: This is really what documentation and specifications are for. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Specifications, `===` was added in [ECMAScript 3rd Edition (ECMA-262)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), December 1999

Comment: It's not "too broad", no, it's just not a terribly useful question and you could have researched it yourself.

Comment: @deceze I was having difficulty finding it on Stack Overflow, (and other places) Yes it may have been a little hasty, but there's been other questions similar to this in the past that have been recieved well, and poorly. Posting a question to SO doesn't mean that I wasn't willing to put the effort into answering it myself, once pushed a little in the right direction, and I don't believe downvotes should be used in cases of 'lack of research effort' if it's still a **relevant** question for the site that doesn't have a duplicate.

The real question lies, is it **relevent**?

Comment: Exactly, a) it seems pretty *irrelevant* to any working Javascript programmer (you can't even really get Javascript versions which don't support `===`) and b) Stack Overflow doesn't necessarily need to be a copy of existing documentation.

Comment: Personally the reason I went hunting for it originally, was to find a summary that didn't require trawling through several standards, and potentially pre-standards. I feel like it's a nice single data point for showing the evolution of the language to other people.

Comment: Up-voted! Good question. The inception date of `===` into the specification is a [pertinent curiosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813590/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the ECMA Standards, as found on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Specifications

---

## Object.is - June 2015

Object.is was introduced in [Standard ECMA-262
6th Edition / June 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.is)

---

## === - December 1999

`===` was introduced in the 3rd edition of ECMAScript, aka `JavaScript 1.3`.

`ECMAScript 3rd Edition (ECMA-262)  Standard`

Adds === and !== operators.

Implemented in JavaScript 1.3 which is dated **December 1999** on [Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

---

## == - June 1997

I suspect `==` predates ECMAScript standards, but the closest standard i can find is

[Standard ECMA-262 June 1997](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) aka `JavaScript 1.0`

However, this is merely the date they were standardized, if they existed pre-standardization, the dates may be incorrect.

Comment: I found some standards from 1996 [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/archive/ecmascript/1996/index.html), predating ES1, that already include `==`.